# Improving database query performance & memory usage listing all data laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, memory, eloquent, query-optimization

I have a `dictionaries` csv file like this (arround 1000 rows):

[image]

Here are the rules:

- Carriers are unique and one `carrier` can have many `dom_int` (one to many)
- Each `dom_int` can have many `group` and one `group` can have many `dom_int` (many to many)
- Each `group` can have many `route`(routes are unique) and one `route` belong to on `group` (one to many)
- Each `route` can have many `sector` (only 2) and one sector belong to one `route` (one to many)

It will look something like this:

```
{
    "VJ": {
        "Domestic": {
            "Group 1": {
                "SGN-BMV-SGN": [
                    "BMV-SGN",
                    "SGN-BMV"
                 ]
                 ...
             },
             ...
         },
         ...
    },
    ...
}
```

My approach is to divide it into tables like below when upload:

- `carriers` table
- `dom_ints` table
- `groups` table
- `routes` table
- `sectors` table

And I also have another big `data` csv file (around 200k rows) with data like below:
[image]

The relationship between this file and the `dictionary` file is through `str_Flight_Route` (Sector in `dictionary` file).

My goal is so simple, I want to list all data of this `data` csv file in only 1 page, with the format as picture below:[image]

But my current big problem is that it takes a huge amount of memory. If I convert all data into a big `php array` and display, it will take at least `1GB memory usage` for 200k rows of data file. But if I store all the data into different small tables and display, it takes event more memory, because I have to loop and query a lot even 3GB of memory.

Can anyone have any other solution help me solve this problem? Displaying all 200k rows of data like that format and still take less memory usage ( below 50M )?

Comment: Part of what you need is a [tag:pivot] operation to take some rows of your data and put them into columns.